# Sign raw transactions in Logic Apps

Tags: ethereum, azure-logic-apps, web3py

I'm new to Logic Apps. What I would like to achieve is to sign and send raw transactions to Ethereum network using Logic Apps service. Currently, what I have done is to transfer ERC20 tokens from the token contract itself in Logic Apps.

What I would like to achieve is to transfer tokens from account to account which is the transfer from the method the ERC20 protocol.

How can I do that in Logic Apps? In my opinion, it's required the sender to sign the raw transaction message.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not familiar with ERC20, since you seem to be using web3py, I believe you can offload the signing to an [Python Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python) which you can [invoke from within a Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions).

As for signing a transaction, looks like this is covered in the [web3py docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction).